# How can I run ssh-add automatically, without a password prompt?

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

I want to communicate between several computers on my network (static Ethernet), through SSH. In order to do that I need to run [`ssh-add`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/ssh-add.1.en) every time I log in on a specific machine.

What can I do so it's set up once and it doesn't ask me for the passphrase every time I log in or reboot my machine?

I know that there is a way where you add some lines to the `bash_profile` file, but I still need to type the password every time I reboot/log in to a specific machine.

```
if [ -z "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] ; then
    eval `ssh-agent -s`
    ssh-add
fi
```

Comment: similar to this question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880024/start-ssh-agent-on-login

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52671286/217408 solved it for me to pass the passphrase from bitwarden

Comment: @steampowered yes - but I think the top answer given here is better and Unix SE is a more appropriate place for this question

Answer (score 480):

This is a typical example of a trade-off between security and convenience. Luckily, there are a number of options. The most appropriate solution depends on the usage scenario and desired level of security.

**ssh-key with passphrase, no** `ssh-agent`

Now the passphrase has to be entered every time the key is used for authentication. While this is the best option from a security standpoint, it offers the worst usability. This may also lead to a weak passphrase being chosen in order to lessen the burden of entering it repeatedly.

**ssh-key with passphrase, with** `ssh-agent`

Adding the following to `~/.bash_profile` will automatically start `ssh-agent` and load the ssh-key(s) on login:

```
if [ -z "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] ; then
  eval `ssh-agent -s`
  ssh-add
fi
```

Now the passphrase must be entered upon every login. While slightly better from a usability perspective, this has the drawback that `ssh-agent` prompts for the passphrase regardless whether the key is to be used or not during the login session. Each new login also spawns a distinct `ssh-agent` instance which remains running with the added keys in memory even after logout, unless explicitly killed.

To kill `ssh_agent` on logout, add the following to `~/.bash_logout`

```
if [ -n "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] ; then
  eval `/usr/bin/ssh-agent -k`
fi
```

or the following to `~/.bash_profile`

```
trap 'test -n "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" && eval `/usr/bin/ssh-agent -k`' 0
```

Creating multiple `ssh-agent` instances can be avoided by creating a persistent communication socket to the agent at a fixed location in the file system, such as in [Collin Anderson's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/217223/43779). This is an improvement over spawning multiple agents instances. However, unless explicitly killed, the decrypted key still remains in memory after logout.

On desktops, ssh-agents included with the desktop environment, such as the [Gnome Keyring SSH Agent](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeKeyring/Ssh), can be a better approach as they typically can be made to prompt for the passphrase the first time the ssh-key is used during a login session and store the decrypted private key in memory until the end of the session.

**ssh-key with passphrase, with** `ssh-ident`

[`ssh-ident`](https://github.com/ccontavalli/ssh-ident) is a utility that can manage `ssh-agent` on your behalf and load identities as necessary. It adds keys only once they are needed, regardless of how many terminals, SSH or login sessions require access to an `ssh-agent`. It can also add and use a different agent and different set of keys depending on the host you are connected to, or the directory `ssh` is invoked from. This allows for isolating keys when using agent forwarding with different hosts. It also allows using multiple accounts on sites like GitHub.

To enable `ssh-ident`, install it and add the following alias to your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
alias ssh='/path/to/ssh-ident'
```

**ssh-key with passphrase, with** `keychain`

[`keychain`](https://github.com/funtoo/keychain) is a small utility which manages `ssh-agent` on your behalf and allows the `ssh-agent` to remain running when the login session ends. On subsequent logins, `keychain` will connect to the existing `ssh-agent` instance. In practice, this means that the passphrase must be be entered only during the first login after a reboot. On subsequent logins, the unencrypted key from the existing `ssh-agent` instance is used. This can also be useful for allowing passwordless RSA/DSA authentication in `cron` jobs without passwordless ssh-keys.

To enable `keychain`, install it and add something like the following to `~/.bash_profile`:

```
eval `keychain --agents ssh --eval id_rsa`
```

From a security point of view, `ssh-ident` and `keychain` are worse than `ssh-agent` instances limited to the lifetime of a particular session, but they offer a high level of convenience. To improve the security of `keychain`, some people add the `--clear` option to their `~/.bash_profile` keychain invocation. By doing this, passphrases must be re-entered on login as above, but `cron` jobs will still have access to the unencrypted keys after the user logs out. The `keychain` [wiki page](https://www.funtoo.org/Funtoo:Keychain) has more information and examples.

**ssh-key without passphrase**

From a security standpoint, this is the worst option since the private key is entirely unprotected in case it is exposed. This is, however, the only way to make sure that the passphrase need not be re-entered after a reboot.

**ssh-key with passphrase, with** `ssh-agent`, **passing passphrase to** `ssh-add` **from script**

While it might seem like a straightforward idea to pass the passphrase to `ssh-add` from a script, e.g. `echo "passphrase\n" | ssh-add`, this is not as straightforward as it seems as `ssh-add` [does not read the passphrase from `stdin`, but opens `/dev/tty` directly for reading](https://superuser.com/questions/569432/why-can-i-see-password-prompts-through-redirecting-output).

This can be [worked around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459182/using-expect-to-pass-a-password-to-ssh) with [`expect`](https://core.tcl-lang.org/expect/index), a tool for automating interactive applications. Below is an example of a script which adds a ssh-key using a passphrase stored in the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh-add /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
expect "Enter passphrase for /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa:"
send "passphrase\n";
expect "Identity added: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa (/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa)"
interact
```

Note that as the passphrase is stored in plaintext in the script, from a security perspective, this is hardly better than having a passwordless ssh-key. If this approach is to be used, it is important to make sure that the `expect` script containing the passphrase has proper permissions set to it, making it readable, writable, and runnable only by the key owner.

Comment: Okay, but when I put your code to ~/.bash_profile I have to type in password every time I login, I don't want that either. I am not concerned about security at all. 

    echo "pass\n" | ssh-add 

doesn't work

Comment: @user1607072 Yeah, that is how the `ssh-agent` snippet in `~/.bash_profile` behaves as explained in the answer. You might want to look at the `keychain` utility. With `keychain` you need to enter the password on first login after reboot, but on subsequent logins `keychain` will connect to an existing `ssh-agent` instance with the decrypted key in memory. Apart from that there's the option of generating a ssh-key without a passphrase, but this is of course not recommended.

Comment: So there is no other way to do it than to leave my passphrase empty? Hmm that is sad. Anyway thanks a lot for your answer, it's the most comprehensive answer I've ever received!

Comment: @user1607072 While I would strongly suggest one of the more secure approaches, there is a way to pass the passphrase to `ssh-add` from a script. The reason `echo "pass\n" | ssh-add` does not work is that `ssh-add` does not read the password from `stdin`, but opens `/dev/tty` directly for reading. Updated the answer to include a workaround for this, using an utility called `expect`.

Comment: Thanks I will try that. I know that it's not secure, but I don't see any other way. I need to communicate with my computers on static network through ssh and I don't want to type in password every time I reboot my network.

Comment: @user1607072 It might be a bit overkill for your use case, but [Kerberos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_(protocol)) in combination with ssh [GSSAPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_Security_Services_Application_Program_Interface) support can also be used for passwordless ssh logins. The corresponding authentication method in ssh is called `gssapi-with-mic`. This is usually used in larger networks, but of course if you have interest in this it might be worth looking into.

Comment: I am running zsh with Prezto and would like to start ssh-agent every time I open terminal. I do have a ssh password. Is it possible?

Comment: @onegrz Typically you'd want only one instance of ssh-agent running. The `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable will point each of your shells to that agent instance. As to how to configure it via Prezto, that sounds like [a new question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). The snippet in the original Q does apply to `zsh` as well, although you'd want to put it in either `.profile` or a `zsh` specific configuration file.

Comment: Sorry, a bit late, what about those GUI tools like `Password and Keys` in Ubuntu or OS X's `Keychain Access`, only the very first time I login into a SSH server they ask me the passphrase and to check something like "*Automatically unlock this key on subsequent logins*". I check it, login into the server, then I reboot, login with my account's password (no passphrase is asked) and this time when I open the SSH connection no passphrase is needed. How do these tools manage this? Does the passphrase become bounded with my account's password so that when I login the key is automatically decrypted?

Comment: is there a way to run "expect" somehow from command line without leaving a file around with the passphrase?

Comment: @tofutim I'd take the password as an argument to the expect script, or possibly pass in as an environment variable.

@Thomas Nyman: Excellent `expect` snippet there. I would however add `expect "Identity added: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa (/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa)"` before the interact, otherwise it would fail in some circumstances.

Comment: keychain requires additional parameters
http://www.funtoo.org/Keychain

Comment: @DmitriyDokshin Can you be more specific? `eval \`keychain --eval id_rsa\`` is a valid usage example also listed on the wiki page you referred to, assuming your private key is in `~/.ssh/id_rsa`.

Comment: @ThomasNyman I'm using `eval 'keychain --eval --agents ssh --inherit any ~/.ssh/my_rsa'`

Comment: I'm curious about making use of systemd to accomplish this and how would that fit into your response?  Also, his is perhaps the most complete answer I've come across!  Thank you for spending the time writing it.

Comment: @ErickBrown: Already answered [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/390631/43779). The SSH Agent unit should be stopped on logout if you have user lingering disabled in the [systemd login manager](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/loginctl.html). If user lingering is enabled, the systemd user instance and the SSH Agent unit are kept running even after the last login session is closed.

Comment: @cmc I reject your edit, but find it meaningfull, you should add it as an answer of it's own.

Comment: Regarding @Collin Anderson's answer you linked-to, you stated: "However, unless explicitly killed, the decrypted key still remains in memory after logout." This is a security consideration in making decisions (which I think is the point you're trying to make), but this is also the _intended behavior_ of his answer, no? I believe the _goal_ of his answer is to make the key persistent until reboot, regardless of logged-in status.

Comment: Consider rephrasing that line to say, "The convenience advantage, but also security concern, is that unless explicitly killed, the decrypted key remains in memory even after logout, and is not cleared until reboot."

Answer (score 155):

Add this to your `~/.bashrc`, then log out and back in to take effect.

```bash
if [ ! -S ~/.ssh/ssh_auth_sock ]; then
  eval `ssh-agent`
  ln -sf "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ~/.ssh/ssh_auth_sock
fi
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=~/.ssh/ssh_auth_sock
ssh-add -l > /dev/null || ssh-add
```

This should only prompt for a password the first time you log in after each reboot. It will keep reusing the same `ssh-agent` as long as it's running.

Comment: very neat, this way you only have one ssh-agent running (:  Multiple agents as in @thomasNyman's second solution seems a security risk to me...

Comment: After researching in various sites and reading various solutions, this one here seems to be the clearest, straight to the point. Very nice. +1

Comment: better to do this: `alias ssh=ssh-check-agent", and have the check-agent version do the above.   that way: a) you only get one agent and b) you only get the agent if you need it

Comment: What is the reason you aren't starting the ssh-agent in the background with the `-s` param? Just curious, I'm still a newbie with Linux (and in my case Debian).

Comment: I think -s is the default, so we're already doing that.

Comment: `ssh-add -l` returns an exit code of 0 when the agent has identities and 1 when it does not so you can cut grep out of the last command and use `ssh-add -l > '/dev/null' || ssh-add`

Comment: This is a good answer, however users would be wise to use the `-t` switch of `ssh-agent`.  There will be a lifetime on all the keys you loaded into the agent.

Comment: Note that `ssh-add` without arguments adds `~/.ssh/id_rsa`. You might want to pass `ssh-add` arguments if your private keys are in another file.

Comment: How do you automatically get rid of the symlink at `~/.ssh/ssh_auth_sock` across reboots? I rebooted my machine, `~/.ssh/ssh_auth_sock` still existed, so the if-statement was false, and as a result `ssh-agent` wasn't started. This was on Git Bash on Windows though, so it could have to do with Windows' meagre support for symlinks.

Comment: @tjalling `/tmp` gets wiped on reboot (assuming it's in memory) so the socket file gets removed, therefore, `test -S` fails because link doesn't point to the socket any more, also `ln -f` forces creation of a new link.

Comment: It's an older answer sir, but it checks out. Many thanks. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @cprn Ah, so the assumption is that `/tmp` is in memory. That explains. On Git Bash on Windows, `/tmp` is mapped to `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp` which is a location on disk (afaik) and the socket is not deleted. I've since added `ps | grep ssh-agent > /dev/null || rm ~/.ssh/ssh_auth_sock > /dev/null 2>&1` to my `~/.bashrc` to remove the symlink. Sounds like I still/instead should clean up the socket file itself then.

Comment: @tjalling I'm guessing you added that before the script in the answer

Comment: @CervEd cleanup of the old files should come before the `if [ ! -S ~/.ssh/ssh_auth_sock ];`, indeed.

Comment: Thanks for this excellent answer. I added a modified version of it to [my personal ssh documentation here](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/tree/master/home/.ssh#auto-starting-the-the-ssh-agent-on-a-remote-ssh-based-development-machine). Among my changes are print statements to explain what's going on, and an `if` statement version of this line to make it more clear what's really happening: `ssh-add -l > /dev/null || ssh-add`.

Comment: For a `.bashrc` script that works in Git Bash and WSL, see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/338514/472652).

Answer (score 34):

Not closely related to the OP's question, but it might be useful to others: [since 7.2.0](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.2), `ssh` has an option that allows adding a key to `ssh-agent` upon first authentication; the option is `AddKeysToAgent` and can be set to `yes`, `no`, `ask`, or `confirm`, system-wide or in your personal `.ssh/config` file.

Comment: Applicable to those who are new to the `.ssh/config` file: this applies to `ssh` and anything that uses `ssh` behind it, for example `scp`, and can be done on a per-host basis.

Comment: It still asks me for password each time I login and try to git pull for example.

Comment: @trainosis The issue is that you probably do not have an ssh-agent instance running to hold the decrypted key(s) in memory for future use. You should only need to enter the password for a given key once per login session when using ssh-agent.

Comment: also note that this can be applied in conjunction with other answers like https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/217223/355088 by just removing the `ssh-add` part

Answer (score 11):

`ssh-agent` caches various unlocked ssh-keys, so you can have ssh-keys protected by passwords, but without having to type them every single time.

In order to cache unlocked keys, it obviously needs to unlock those keys. For unlocking keys that are locked with a passphrase, it obviously needs to know these passphrases.

Any method that does not require authorization from a human being (e.g. "typing in a password") will not only make your system insecure; it will also render the entire purpose of the ssh-agent meaningless.

Having said all this, you can simply use ssh-keys that are not password protected (hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> when asked for a password during key-generation).
Since there isn't any password, `ssh-agent` doesn't need to ask you for one in order to (not) cache it.

Comment: I agree, as long as your keys are properly user-only-permissioned, there is little advantage to ssh-agent over permissionless keys.   i like to ssh into a login server, and then, that server has a bunch of permssionless keys, each of which can only be used to unlock one other server.  the login server does nothing else, so it's much harder to hack/spoof, etc... the other servers have no password access, are key-only.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a workaround to automate your SSH passphrase.

1. Create a one-liner script which prints your passphrase to standard output, e.g.:

   ```
    echo 'echo MY_SSH_PASSWORD' > ~/.print_ssh_password && chmod 700 ~/.print_ssh_password
   ```

   **Important: Ensure you copy the leading space to [prevent storing your password to your history](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6475524/55075).**

And use one of the below methods.

- using a standard input approach:

  ```
  cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa | SSH_ASKPASS=~/.print_ssh_password ssh-add -
  ```
- or [named pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe) approach:

  1. Create a [named pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe) (you could also try a [process substitution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/235290/21471)):

     ```
     mkfifo --mode 0600 ~/.ssh_fifo
     ```
  2. Run `ssh-add` by specifying the program used for the authentication:

     ```
     cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa >~/.ssh_fifo | SSH_ASKPASS=~/.print_ssh_password ssh-add ~/.ssh_fifo
     ```

  See: [`man ssh-add`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-0210/6m6nb7mlq/index.html) to read more about `SSH_ASKPASS`.

Comment: The `echo my_passphrase` is a big security hole. First after you have typed it, the password is in clear text in the history file of what ever shell you use. And second command line arguments are world readable on Unix (`ps -ef`). **Never put passwords in command line arguments!**

Comment: @ceving Adding extra leading space solves the problem with the history file. Added extra info.

Comment: @kenorb: That doesn't solve the bigger problem of the password visible in `ps` output. The history file is typically only readable by the owning user anyway, but the command lines are readable by all users on a system.

Answer (score 6):

I won't recommend you ssh-add (which need to open a ssh-agent) at login.  This is because you can't control when the ssh-agent section ends, and can create security risk when you need not use the keyfiles at one login section.

Rather, I recommend to write a script which opens a ssh-agent's section sub-shell, with all keyfiles auto added, and be called when needed to use ssh. If you could adopt so, read on.

You would have two choices:

1. Remove all passphrases for your keys, which have **weak security** if your key files are stolen.  (thus *not recommended*)
2. Use the same passphrase for your keys. Then when you `ssh-add keyfile1 keyfile2 ...`, you will only need to type the passphrase once, per section.

In both cases, you could write such script file "ssh_keys_section.sh" as below:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This script run a ssh-agent on a sub-shell and automatically ssh-add all keyfiles at once.
# This agent ends when you type `exit` to close the sub-shell.
exec ssh-agent bash -c "ssh-add /path/to/keyfile1 /path/to/keyfile2 ...; exec bash"
```

Remarks:

- Command to change or delete passphrase: `ssh-keygen -p -f keyfile`
- Within the sub-shell, you might even fork more terminals which share the same unlocked keys, by using maybe a command like `/path/to/yourterminal &` (depends on OS)

Comment: E.g. On Windows within Cygwin, `/path/to/yourterminal &` ==> `mintty &`

Comment: Remark: after use, close the session with `ctrl-d` or `exit`, just like you have invoked a nested `bash` shell and need to close it.

Answer (score 3):

I used to use the script mentioned by steampowered, I've made the below one now, because it doesn't leave files lying around.

**Working on `zsh` shell only.**

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

AGENT_BIN=`which ssh-agent`
AGENT_ADD_BIN=`which ssh-add`
AGENT_PID=`ps -fe | grep ${AGENT_BIN} | awk -vuser=$USER -vcmd="$AGENT_BIN" '$1==user && $8==cmd{print $2;exit;}'`
if [ -z "$AGENT_BIN" ]; then
    echo "no ssh agent found!";
    return
fi
if [ "" -eq "$AGENT_PID" ]; then
    if read -sq "YN?Do you want to unlock your ssh keys?"; then
        echo ""
        output=`$AGENT_BIN | sed 's/echo/#echo/g'`
        eval $output
        $AGENT_ADD_BIN
    fi
else
    for f in "/proc/"*
    do
        cmdline=`cat "$f/cmdline"`
        if [ "${AGENT_BIN}" -ef "${cmdline}" ]; then
            export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=`cat $f/net/unix | grep --binary-file=text -oP '((/[^/]*?)+/ssh-[^/]+/agent\.\d+$)'`
            export SSH_AGENT_PID=${f##*/}
            break;
        fi
    done
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

***If you are running seahorse as your password manager***
... Which you probably are ;D

Another solution that achieves the goal you are looking for is simply adding the ssh keys to seahorse for automatic unlock upon login. The major benefit to this is that you never have to enter a password for the keys after you login through gdm, or whatever your loging in with even if the keys have a password. This REQUIRES both the private key and the public key. They also MUST follow a naming convention for seahorse. The default is acceptable (id_rsa for private key and id_rsa.pub for public key... Really anything that is *privatekeyname* and *privatekeyname.pub*)

To add you ssh key to seahorse for automatic unlock upon login;
(on fedora25, I'm not sure where the path is on other distros though its most likely very similar)

```
/lib64/seahorse/seahorse-ssh-askpass /path/to/keys/here
```

For me, it was

```
/lib64/seahorse/seahorse-ssh-askpass ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

(seahorse will automatically assume that the public key in my case was id_rsa.pub)

After executing the command, seahorse will pop open a cute little gtk password field to enter the password for the private key into. or just leave it blank if you generated the key without a password.

Seahorse won't prompt you if everything went okay. You will need to attempt to ssh into the target machine. Then seahorse will prompt you to unlock the key with a password graphically (THIS WILL ONLY HAPPEN ONCE) again but it should look a little different this time ;P (this is also the part where seahorse does some seahorse to ssh-add magic I believe), and offer the ***OPTION*** to unlock the key upon login, you must check this option to achieve your goal.

Just because I didn't read all the answers, I would recommend undoing what everyone told you to do with ssh-add before attempting this answer. Doing so otherwise might result in something bad happening to your keys, idk.

Answer (score 2):

Single sign on solution for SSH could lead me to [`pam_ssh`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_ssh).

According to [this article](https://wiki.sabayon.org/index.php?title=HOWTO:_Passwordless_SSH_with_Single_Signon), the concept is:

> If you work with multiple *nix-based machines via ssh, you are probably tired of constantly having to enter your password every time you want to access another box. There is a secure way to allow you to access every machine, that you have ssh access to, without having to enter another password (other than the one you signed on with originally.)

---

> This is actually quite simple to do, you basically just create a public/private key pair to authenticate yourself to your other machines, then have PAM spawn an agent to load your keys after you logon, providing a single signon solution to accessing all your remote machines. This guide will walk you through setting this up.

I have not verified this would actually work.

Answer (score 2):

```
if [ ! -S ${HOME}/.ssh/ssh_auth_sock ]; then
  eval $(ssh-agent)
  ln -sf "${SSH_AUTH_SOCK}" ${HOME}/.ssh/ssh_auth_sock
fi
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=${HOME}/.ssh/ssh_auth_sock

ssh_keys=$(find -E ~/.ssh -type f -regex '.*(rsa$|pem)')
ssh_agent_keys=$(ssh-add -l | awk '{key=NF-1; print $key}')

for k in "${ssh_keys}"; do
    for l in "${ssh_agent_keys}"; do
        if [[ ! "${k}" = "${l}" ]]; then
            ssh-add "${k}" > /dev/null 2>&1
        fi
    done
done
```

Comment: Description is encouraged

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by [Collin Anderson's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/217223/), I wrote an alternative script (that needs to be put inside of your `.bashrc` file) which unlike his, actually works in an environment like WSL (where the `/tmp` directory doesn't get cleared, which is what his solution relies on):

```bash
source ~/.ssh/agent_out &> /dev/null
if ! ps -p $SSH_AGENT_PID &> /dev/null
then
  ssh-agent > ~/.ssh/agent_out
  source ~/ssh/agent_out &> /dev/null
fi
```

To understand what this script is actually doing, let’s consider what it would do the first time it’s run:

1. It spins up an SSH agent, stores the output of the `ssh-agent` command inside a file called `agent_out` in the user’s `.ssh` directory for later use. The output of the `ssh-agent` command contains statements to assign the right values to environment variables like `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` and `SSH_AGENT_PID`.
2. For every new shell session, it first executes the output of the last `ssh-agent` command which was stored in the `~/.ssh/agent_out` file, and then checks whether the process with the ID included in `SSH_AGENT_PID` actually exists or not. If it doesn’t, it performs the first step.

This, coupled with the new SSH config option `AddKeysToAgent` — see [the manual](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/kinetic/en/man5/ssh_config.5.html) —, would yield a nice user experience, and eliminate the need for third-party tools like `keychain` and `ssh-ident` for the most part:

`~/.ssh/config`:

```
AddKeysToAgent yes
```

Comment: What if the PID is taken by another process that is not ssh-agent?

Answer (score 1):

```
SSH_ENV="$HOME/.ssh/environment"

function start_agent {
     echo "Initialising new SSH agent..."
     /usr/bin/ssh-agent | sed 's/^echo/#echo/' > "${SSH_ENV}"
     echo succeeded
     chmod 600 "${SSH_ENV}"
     . "${SSH_ENV}" > /dev/null
     /usr/bin/ssh-add;
}

# Source SSH settings, if applicable

if [ -f "${SSH_ENV}" ]; then
     . "${SSH_ENV}" > /dev/null
     #ps ${SSH_AGENT_PID} doesn't work under cywgin
     ps -ef | grep ${SSH_AGENT_PID} | grep ssh-agent$ > /dev/null || {
         start_agent;
     }
else
     start_agent;
fi
```

Giving credit here:  https://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2001-06/msg00537.html

This solution is also endorsed here:  http://mah.everybody.org/docs/ssh

Answer (score 1):

My setup on macOS is as follow (in `.zshrc`, or `.bash_profile` for bash folks):

```
# Kill then Load the ssh-agent and set the necessary env variables it outputs
sshRestart() {
    # if all else fails
    # pkill -u $(whoami) ssh-agent;

    if [ -n "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] ; then
        eval `/usr/bin/ssh-agent -k`
    fi
    eval `ssh-agent -s`
    ssh-add ~/.ssh/YOUR_KEY_FILE
    echo "Restarted SSH agent"
}

if [ -z "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] || [[ $SSH_AUTH_SOCK == *"/private/tmp/"* ]] ; then
    eval `ssh-agent -s` > /dev/null 2>&1
    ssh-add ~/.ssh/YOUR_KEY_FILE > /dev/null 2>&1
fi
```

The `|| [[ $SSH_AUTH_SOCK == *"/private/tmp/"* ]]` part is necessary on macOS because the default value is `/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.SOMETHINGHERE/Listeners`. Otherwise @Thomas Nyman comprehensive answer fails because `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` is always set to something.

Then in `.zlogout` (or `.bash_logout` for bash folks):

```
if [ -n "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] ; then
    eval `/usr/bin/ssh-agent -k`
fi
```

Tested on macOS Mojave 10.14.5

Answer (score 1):

This has been very well explained by GitHub on [Auto-launching ssh-agent on Git for Windows](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases#auto-launching-ssh-agent-on-git-for-windows), which in turn works for Linux also.

You can run `ssh-agent` automatically when you open bash or Git shell. Copy the following lines and paste them into your `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc` file in Git shell:

```bash
env=~/.ssh/agent.env

agent_load_env () { test -f "$env" && . "$env" >| /dev/null ; }

agent_start () {
    (umask 077; ssh-agent >| "$env")
    . "$env" >| /dev/null ; }

agent_load_env

# agent_run_state: 0=agent running w/ key; 1=agent w/o key; 2= agent not running
agent_run_state=$(ssh-add -l >| /dev/null 2>&1; echo $?)

if [ ! "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] || [ $agent_run_state = 2 ]; then
    agent_start
    ssh-add
elif [ "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] && [ $agent_run_state = 1 ]; then
    ssh-add
fi

unset env
```

If your private key is not stored in one of the default locations (like `~/.ssh/id_rsa`), you'll need to tell your SSH authentication agent where to find it. To add your key to ssh-agent, type `ssh-add ~/path/to/my_key`.

**Tip:** If you want `ssh-agent` to forget your key after some time, you can configure it to do so by running `ssh-add -t <seconds>`.

Answer (score 1):

**The easiest solution does not have to be bad.**

You need neither `ssh-agent` nor `ssh-add` when you use a passwordless private key, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48290333/11154841.

That does not need to be insecure: you simply need to delete both keys of the key pair right after their usage. That means, you must delete the public key on the server and delete the private key on the client. It goes without saying: never use them again, do not even keep a backup somewhere.

*Mind that you can create the public key from a private key, but not the other way round.* Normally, it should suffice to simply delete the public key from the registered keys on your Git portal, but they should better be both deleted, so that the same public key can never ever be used again. Even if someone had stolen your private key, it would be of no use if you simply never use its public key again.

With a passwordless private key, you can even use it in Docker to get around any password entries. You can clone a git repo without any password, the passwordless private key is all you need. See [Dockerfile: clone repo with passwordless private key. Errors: “authentication agent” or “read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty”](https://superuser.com/questions/1633085/dockerfile-clone-repo-with-passwordless-private-key-errors-authentication-ag) as an example.

Comment: I guess using a new key pair every time will be much more hassle than entering a password.

Comment: @EvgenKo423 You are right, obviously. But if you are not allowed to use pw security, or if you use dockerfile which does not accept console entries when running, then this helps. There is also another approach to use a deployment token, then you do not need to upload your own private key, but you use just the command including the token, then. This is a once-off effort but not that secure anymore if that token gets spread.

Comment: But using an ssh agent anyway has other advantages such as *agent forwarding*

Comment: @Nephanth It might be the easiest solution here, but not the best. The only good use case is if you need to get docker to run through without any console action. in such cases, you would need a trick like this (linked above). Without Docker, you are better off with the ssh agent.

Answer (score 1):

I [really like this answer by @Collin Anderson](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/217223/114401), and I upvoted it. I then added a modified version of it to [my personal ssh documentation here](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/tree/master/home/.ssh#auto-starting-the-the-ssh-agent-on-a-remote-ssh-based-development-machine). Among my changes are print statements to explain what's going on, and an `if` statement to replace this line (`ssh-add -l > /dev/null || ssh-add`) to make it more clear what's really happening.

Here is my version below.

#### Description:

Auto-start the ssh agent and add necessary keys once per reboot.

This is recommended to be added to your `~/.bash_aliases` (preferred) or `~/.bashrc` file on any
remote ssh server development machine that you generally ssh into, and from which you must ssh
into other machines or servers, such as to push code to GitHub over ssh. If you only graphically
log into this machine, however, there is no need to do this, as Ubuntu's Gnome window manager,
for instance, will automatically start and manage the `ssh-agent` for you instead.

#### Code:

```bsh
if [ ! -S ~/.ssh/ssh_auth_sock ]; then
    echo "'ssh-agent' has not been started since the last reboot." \
         "Starting 'ssh-agent' now."
    eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
    ln -sf "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ~/.ssh/ssh_auth_sock
fi
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=~/.ssh/ssh_auth_sock
# see if any key files are already added to the ssh-agent, and if not, add them
ssh-add -l > /dev/null
if [ "$?" -ne "0" ]; then
    echo "No ssh keys have been added to your 'ssh-agent' since the last" \
         "reboot. Adding default keys now."
    ssh-add
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Not recommend but you could just remove the password outright with:

```
ssh-keygen -p
```

Then leave the new password blank

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
ssh-add -L|grep identities > /dev/null && ssh-add /path/to/ssh/private/key
```

Comment: I don't see how this relates to the question, which is about not being prompted for the password on subsequent logins.

Answer (score 0):

In order to add a (possibly passwordless) key and ensure that `ssh-add` will not prompt for a password, no matter what, even when running under [X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System):

```
DISPLAY= ssh-add -k /path/to/key </dev/null &>/dev/null
```

Exit status indicates success or failure.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I am aware of is to use a PAM login script I adapted from previous work because I couldn't find a satisfying answer in this question.

Your passphrase gets stored encrypted with your system password and a heavy derivation function. At login, your system password is used to decrypt your passphrase and add it to the agent.

https://github.com/capocasa/systemd-user-pam-ssh

The advantage over every other solution presented is that it combines security equivalent to running ssh-add manually at boot with zero effort. It requires no extra tools and has one extra dependency that's already installed by default on most systems (OpenSSL).

Answer (score 0):

Answering as a future note for myself: on Fedora do nothing!
Simply pull git repository with this key.
Then gui will popup and ask you whether to store it in keyring. Now you can use this key automatically after login.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the definitive script.

Update $PASSW, then copy-paste it in your Terminal

```
# <sshpass> via typinator
# Updated: 2017-01-18_21h36
#
# apt-get update -y; apt-get install expect -qy

# Pass this value to ssh-add
PASSW="myfancypass123"

# Define a name for this script
THIS_SCRIPT="$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S-%N)".sh

# Create a fresh directory to work from / Clean up
rm -rf ~/temp; mkdir -p ~/temp; cd ~/temp; ls -la


# Output our bash script file - BEGIN
cat <<< '
#!/bin/bash

set -u     # Stop if an unbound variable is referenced
set -e     # Stop on first error
export HISTIGNORE="expect*";

# Normal CMDs
echo && echo "The process should take about 10 seconds:" && echo
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"; sleep 0.5;

# Define VAR passed when this bash-script was launched
password="$@"

# Launch the expect magic
expect -c "
    spawn ssh-add /root/.ssh/id_rsa
    expect "?assword:"
    send \"$password\r\"
    expect "?password:"
    send \"$password\r\"
    expect eof"

export HISTIGNORE="";
export password="";
' > $THIS_SCRIPT
# Output our bash script file - END


# Ensure we are in the right path
cd ~/temp; ls -la; sleep 1;

# Run the bash script
chmod +x ./$THIS_SCRIPT; ./$THIS_SCRIPT "$PASSW"; unset password;

# Clean up
rm -rf ~/temp; mkdir -p ~/temp; cd ~/temp; ls -la
```