# How to start and use ssh-agent as systemd service?

Tags: systemd, ssh-agent

1. How to start **ssh-agent** as **systemd** service? There are some suggestions in the net, but they are not complete.
2. How to add automatically unencrypted keys if **ssh-agent** service was started successfully? Probably, adding keys from the list of `~/.ssh/.session-keys` would be good.
3. How to set `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` in any login session afterwards? The most correct way is to push it from **ssh-agent** service to **systemd-logind** service (have no idea if it's ever possible). The plain naive way is just add it to `/etc/profile`.

Comment: What's missing from the suggestions on the net?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

- To create a systemd `ssh-agent` service, you need to create a file in `~/.config/systemd/user/ssh-agent.service` because `ssh-agent` is user isolated.

  ```
  [Unit]
  Description=SSH key agent

  [Service]
  Type=simple
  Environment=SSH_AUTH_SOCK=%t/ssh-agent.socket
  ExecStart=/usr/bin/ssh-agent -D -a $SSH_AUTH_SOCK

  [Install]
  WantedBy=default.target
  ```
- Add

  ```
  SSH_AUTH_SOCK="${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}/ssh-agent.socket"
  ```

  to `~/.config/environment.d/ssh_auth_socket.conf`.
- Finally enable and start this service.

  ```
  systemctl --user enable --now ssh-agent
  ```
- And, if you are using ssh version higher than 7.2.

  ```
  echo 'AddKeysToAgent  yes' >> ~/.ssh/config
  ```

  This will instruct the ssh client to always add the key to a running agent, so there's no need to `ssh-add` it beforehand.

Note that when you create the `~/.ssh/config` file you may need to run:

```
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config
```

or

```
chown $USER ~/.ssh/config
```

Otherwise, you might receive the `Bad owner or permissions on ~/.ssh/config` error.

Comment: `launchd` on OS X is set to start ssh-agent when a Unix socket is accessed (and the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` variable is prepopulated with the path...) (like `inetd`, but a Unix socket). This seems possible with `systemd` as well.  (Whether a system-wide service is an option for a per-user service might be interesting to see....)

Comment: I get `Failed to execute operation: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1` when I run `systemctl --user enable ssh-agent` on centos7

Comment: You can make ssh-agent exit after your last session by adding `After=systemd-user-sessions.service user-runtime-dir@%i.service dbus.service` and `Requires=user-runtime-dir@%i.service` to the `[Unit]` section.

Comment: @AlecMev `Environment` seems to be useful for other services started with systemd that might want to know `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`.

Comment: This setup persists through reSTART in Arch (i.e., logout/login, or i3 `$mod` `<Shift>` `e` ). It does not survive a `reboot` or a 'Reddit-tier IT Support stock answer' (i.e., "Turn it off then back on").

Answer (score 2):

This is not supported if you are using centos 7 because it will not support the `--user` flag of `systemctl`.  See this centos bug report, [Systemd User Support is Broken on Delivery](https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=8767)