# How to start a systemd service running in an ssh-agent?

Tags: systemd, ssh-agent

The answer to [How to start and use ssh-agent as systemd service?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/339840/157438) gets us a running ssh-agent. How can you write another systemd service file so that its process runs under that ssh-agent? In particular I want to run an emacs service so that I can edit remote files using tramp.

This service file starts emacs but it's not running under ssh-agent.

```
[Unit]
Description=Emacs text editor
Documentation=info:emacs man:emacs(1) https://gnu.org/software/emacs/
After=ssh-agent.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/emacs --fg-daemon
ExecStop=/usr/bin/emacsclient --eval "(kill-emacs)"
Environment=SSH_AUTH_SOCK=%t/ssh-agent.socket
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Comment: I am stuck on this too :-( The problem is the `Environment` setting, right? What should the `%t` expand to ?

Comment: Here's what worked for me: `ENVIRONMENT=SSH_AUTH_SOCK=%t/keyring/ssh`