# Passphrase required despite having setup authenticated keys via ssh

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-agent

I continue to get a passphrase prompt with ssh despite already having set up the public key authetnitication on the remote server. I have already in the past done the following:

Local Server

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh/
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
eval `ssh-agent`
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa (enter passphrase here)
```

Remote Server

```
Set up a ~/.ssh/authorizedkeys (this is my id_rsa.pub file from my local server)
```

After disconnecting from my local server and logging back in, I still need to enter my passphrase despite having already added the identity to my key agent. It continues to be prompted.

This is what my config file settings look like as well:

```
Host *
  User name
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UpdateHostKeys yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  PubkeyAuthentication yes
  Port 22
```

Thanks in advanced

Comment: When you disconnect from your local server, presumably your session is terminated, and along it your instance of `ssh-agent`. This is expected.

Comment: Is there any way to keep the ssh-agent running? This is because I need to run automated pipelines running via a job scheduler

Comment: Possibly relating: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/90853/315749. If ssh-agent is actually killed upon logout, the way to prevent it will likely depend on the operating system and service/session manager you are using on the local system. Can you please edit this information into your question?

Comment: Could be permissions: (1) are you the owner of `~/.ssh/id_rsa`? (2) are you the owner of `~/.ssh`? (3) are you the owner of `~/` and (4) are permissions `750` on `~/`?