# Permanently adding ssh keys for Amazon EC2 logins and link to GitHub?

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

I've started using Amazon EC2 recently.
I've setup a "permanent" Spot instance, I log in using ssh keys, then I clone some GitHub repos (using another ssh key pair).

The problem is, dispite the fact that EC2 instance is permanent, each new login session I do, I have to setup the ssh keys all over again (both to log in to EC2, and to pull repo from GitHub into EC2), with the following commands:

```
> eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
> ssh-add ~/.ssh/mykey
```

Why isn't this permanently added?

Comment: As to "why" - because you're not telling the system to do it each time you log in. Logging out stops the `ssh-agent` process.

Comment: Dang it, I picked the wrong dupe. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90853/how-can-i-run-ssh-add-automatically-without-a-password-prompt
The next person to read this: please mark as dupe :)

Comment: Are you telling me that just running the agent would be enough to make this a permanent key, without having to add it `ssh-add ~/.ssh/mykey` each time?